# Syntax Error: Token ':' is an unexpected token when passing variable to directive

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

I have a directive called `iframely` and I it inside an `ng-repeat` like this:

```
<iframely url="iterator.url"></iframely>
```

This just treats the value as the string `"iterator.url"`, not the actual `.url` value. To experiment, I just put in a URL directly:

```
<iframely url="https://soundcloud.com/braxe1/braxe-one-more-chance"></iframely>
```

Which gives me the `Syntax Error: Token ':' is an unexpected token` error. The closest I've gotten to passing this value to the directive is:

```
<iframely url="'{{iterator.url}}'"></iframely> // note double and single quotes
```

This resolves the URL parameter of `iterator`, but also passes it along with the `' '` single-quotes as part of the string.

---

EDIT: Also tried that without the single quotes.

```
<iframely url="{{iterator.url}}"></iframely>
```

And got `Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '{' invalid key at column 2 of the expression [{{iterator.url}}] starting at [{iterator.url}}]`

What is the correct way to do this?

---

EDIT2: Here is the code for the directive:

```
angular.module( 'iframely', [])

.directive( 'iframely', [ '$http', '$sce', function ( $http, $sce ) {
    return {
        replace: true,
        restrict: "E",
        scope: {
            url: '='
        },
        template: '<div ng-bind-html="content"></div>',
        link: function ( scope, element, attrs ) {
            $http( {
                url: 'http://localhost:8061/iframely',
                method: 'GET',
                params: {
                    url: attrs.url
                }
            })
            .then( function ( result ) {
                scope.content = $sce.trustAsHtml( result.data.html )
            })
        }
    }
}])
```

Comment: url="{{iterator.url}}" without single quotes...

Comment: @micronyks Actually, that was the firs one I tried. `Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '{' invalid key at column 2 of the expression [{{iterator.url}}] starting at [{iterator.url}}]`

Comment: Can you post the code for your directive?

Comment: @adam0101 Added above.

Comment: Try changing `url: '='` to `url: '@'`, then use the curly braces without the quotes.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You must replace  `url: '='`

By `url: '@'`

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile

Answer (score 3):

Change your directive to be the following:

```
angular.module( 'iframely', [])

.directive( 'iframely', [ '$http', '$sce', function ( $http, $sce ) {
    return {
        replace: true,
        restrict: "E",
        scope: {
            url: '@'
        },
        template: '<div ng-bind-html="content"></div>',
        link: function ( scope, element, attrs ) {
            $http( {
                url: 'http://localhost:8061/iframely',
                method: 'GET',
                params: {
                    url: scope.url
                }
            })
            .then( function ( result ) {
                scope.content = $sce.trustAsHtml( result.data.html )
            })
        }
    }
}])
```

Notice the '@' in the scope and the `url: scope.url`.